# ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,1) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-image

This is the code I'm working on, the edge detection part works perfectly it's just that the corrected image is not being plotted for some reason. Please advice.

The error points to the 2nd last code line, just above plt.show()

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import hough_line, hough_line_peaks
from skimage.transform import rotate
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import mode

image = rgb2gray(imread("/opt/oracle/app/Raunak/skew11.jpeg"))
edges = canny(image)

tested_angles = np.deg2rad(np.arange(0.1, 180.0))
h, theta, d = hough_line(edges, theta=tested_angles)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 16))

ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(image, cmap="gray")
ax[0].set_title('Input image')
ax[0].set_axis_off()
ax[1].imshow(edges, cmap="gray")

origin = np.array((0, image.shape[1]))

for _, angle, dist in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)):
    y0, y1 = (dist - origin * np.cos(angle)) / np.sin(angle)
    ax[1].plot(origin, np.array([y0, y1]).flatten(), '-r')

    
ax[1].set_xlim(origin)
ax[1].set_ylim((edges.shape[0], 0))
ax[1].set_axis_off()
ax[1].set_title('Detected lines')

def skew_angle_hough_transform(image):
    edges = canny(image)
    tested_angles = np.deg2rad(np.arange(0.1, 180.0))

    h, theta, d = hough_line(edges, theta=tested_angles)
    accum, angles, dists = hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d)

    most_common_angle = mode(np.around(angles, decimals=2))[0]
    skew_angle = np.rad2deg(most_common_angle - np.pi/2)
    return skew_angle

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(20,20))

ax[0].imshow(image, cmap="gray")
ax[0].imshow(rotate(image, skew_angle_hough_transform(image), cval=1), cmap="gray")

plt.show()
```

Comment: traceback please.

Comment: Would you give the full error message outputted by your code.